# How to get data from async request in reactjs and add it to React-bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to add React-bootstrap Modal when website open for the every time, model should always pop up in center with the details and with option of close  the model.
I am getting the data from a async request Now if in my json data if "show" is true then only display the "data" from the json to the p tag tried this approach but it fails on close buton

i tried this approach bit it fails throws error

```
 const handleClosed = () => setItems(items.map(item => {return item.show = false}));
TypeError: items.map is not a function
```

```
const Modals = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchItems();
    },[])

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const data = await fetch("url");
      const item = await data.json();
      setItems(item);
    }

    const handleClosed = () => setItems(items.map(item => {return item.show = false}));

    return (
      <div>

       <Modal
          show={items.show}
          onHide={handleClosed}
          size="lg"
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                 <b>Public Notice</b> 
      </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
              <p>
              {items.show}
              </p>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
              <Button onClick={handleClosed}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>

     </div>
    );
  };

  export default Modals;
```

Comment: After this edit you still got error? If not, remove error from question.

Comment: @amin mohammadi error removed

Answer (score 0):

Init items with `[]` will fix the error:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be not able to use map on the items. items object return from the fetch API is not an array.

You could initialize the items to an object.

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState({});
```

You could use directly items.show and items.data .

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by

```
const Modals = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchItems();
    },[])

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const data = await fetch("url");
      const item = await data.json();
      setItems(item);
    }

    const handleClosed = () => setItems(items.show = false}));

    return (
      <div>

       <Modal
          show={items.show}
          onHide={handleClosed}
          size="lg"
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                 <b>Public Notice</b> 
      </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
              <p>
              {items.show}
              </p>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
              <Button onClick={handleClosed}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>

     </div>
    );
  };

  export default Modals;
```